# $_POST['data'] is not defined, if data is too large

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I would like to send a ~10MB json data in a textarea named "data". If the data is 1-2KB, then it works perfectly. But with a large json, the `$_POST['data']` is empty for some reason.

I can't upload the json otherwise, because it is generated clientside, it's not a file.

I've tried this code, but still not working:

```
form.setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
```

---

**Edit**

With this settings it is still not working:

```
memory_limit = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
```

---

**Edit2**

If I switch from php 5.4 to 5.6, then I get an 500 error page, with no details written on the screen.

Comment: try to increase increasing the value of `max_input_vars` in the `php.ini` file

Comment: the only one input is the `data` textarea

Comment: what version of php are you running??

Comment: Did you restart the web server after you made the changes?

Comment: `5.4` if I switch to `5.6` i get a 500 error during the upload, but no description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change `post_max_size` to enough (20MB) in  the `php.ini` file.

By default, `PHP` permits a maximum file upload of 2MB.

Two PHP configuration options control the maximum upload size: `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. Both can be set to, say, `20M` for 20 megabyte file sizes or higher if required.

Answer (score 3):

try changing you post_max_size in

```
 php.ini

 post_max_size=20M
```

Answer (score 2):

Beside others have already mentioned, you can also try to set it in `.htaccess` if you are running in Apache

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 25M
```

Other Method, if you are running as CGI/FastCGI, you can try to create a `.user.ini` and put it where your upload.php script is located

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 40M
```